# The name 'Blank' does not exist in current context, C#

Tags: c#, oop, methods, integer

So I'm trying to call an integer from a method to another but it keeps telling me that the name doesn't exist in current context.

```
using System;
namespace app

{    
    class Program
    {
        // FUN VALUE
        static int funVal(int[] arr)
        {
            long unixTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            int fun = (int) unixTime % 100;
            return fun;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           int Fun = funVal(fun);
           Console.WriteLine(Fun);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried making a separate class for it, changing the return variable. I want it to display the value in the main method so it can be accessed later on by different methods, however its proving to be difficult

Edit: Never mind i was just really out of it yesterday, Anyway i made it work now here's the code but i took it a step further and made it into classes.

```
using System;
namespace app

{
    class funDet 
    {
        // FUN VALUE
        public static int fun;
        
        public static int funVal(){
        long unixTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        
        fun = (int) unixTime % 100;
        return fun;
        }

    }
    
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args){
           
            funDet.funVal();
           Console.WriteLine(funDet.fun);
            
            

        }
}

   
}
```

Comment: Suggested reading: **[Scope of Variables in C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/)**  also **[Basic Concepts - Declarations in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#73-declarations)**

Comment: The name `fun` is a variable locally scoped within the function `funVal`,  it has no meaning within the function `Main`. Your question would be much better if you elaborated on your comment _"it keeps telling me that the name doesn't exist in current context."_. What name? What context?

Answer (score 3):

But there's no `fun` variable in method Main. Your method `funVal` even doesn't use its argument, remove the argument.